# R Error unexpected parenthesis while using For loop with multiple variables

Tags: r

I am new to R and writing a stock trading model. The initial working code is below.

```
Initiate Signal
rsi <- RSI(price, day)  #rsi is the lag of RSI
for (i in (day+1): length(price)){
  if (rsi[i] < 30){  #buy one more unit if rsi < 30
    signal[i] <- 1
  } else if (rsi[i] < 50){ #no change if rsi < 50
    signal[i] <- 0
  } else {         #sell  if rsi > 50
    signal[i] <- -1
  }
}
```

The problem with above is that it keeps generating trading signal everytime RSI is less than 30. Hence i created a dummy_var which is updated during the loop. A sell is triggered when there is an existing buy signal i.e.if the value of dummy_var= 2 and buy when dummy_var=1. But i keep getting this error message - ***Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"*** . Kindly help.

```
for (i in (day+1): length(price)){
  if (dummy_var=2){
    (rsi[i] < 50)  #no change if rsi < 50
    signal[i] <- 0
    dummy_var <- 2
  } else if (dummy_var = 2){
    (rsi[i] > 50) # sell if great than 50
    signal[i] <- -1
    dummy_var <- 2
  } else (rsi[i] < 30){
    signal[i] <- 1
    (dummy_var <- 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `(rsi[i] < 50)  #no change if rsi < 50` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your condition:

```r
if (dummy_var=2)
```

The `=` is used to assign a value. In your case you want to check if `dummy_var` equals `2`, therefore you have to use

```r
if (dummy_var == 2)
```